# How to copy all files from folders and subfolders into one folder using PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, folder, file

I have to copy all files to single location and add prefix to all files while copying to new root folder.
For example, say that I have the following folder hierarchy:

Folder1

```
     File1

     Folder2

         File2

     Folder3

         File3

         Folder4

              File4
```

I want to perform PowerShell Script that results in:

Folder1

```
  LC1_File1

  LC2_File2

  LC3_File3

  LC4_File4
```

Is there any powershell script which could do that

Answer (score 0):

This script uses PowerShell to copy all files and folders from one document library to another document library.  This script will allow you to copy an entire document library, along with user-defined metadata from one site collection to another.

```
$ver = $host | select version 
if($Ver.version.major -gt 1) {$Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"} 
if(!(Get-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ea 0)) 
{ 
Write-Progress -Activity "Loading Modules" -Status "Loading Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" 
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 
} 

## 
#Set Static Variables 
## 

$SourceWebURL = "http://www.contoso.com" 
$SourceLibraryTitle = "Shared Documents" 
$DestinationWebURL = "http://archive.contoso.com/WWWArchive" 
$DestinationLibraryTitle = "Shared Documents" 

## 
#Begin Script 
## 

$sWeb = Get-SPWeb $SourceWebURL 
$sList = $sWeb.Lists | ? {$_.Title -eq $SourceLibraryTitle} 
$dWeb = Get-SPWeb $DestinationWebURL 
$dList = $dWeb.Lists | ? {$_.title -like $DestinationLibraryTitle} 

$AllFolders = $sList.Folders 
$RootFolder = $sList.RootFolder 
$RootItems = $RootFolder.files 

foreach($RootItem in $RootItems) 
{ 
    $sBytes = $RootItem.OpenBinary() 
    $dFile = $dList.RootFolder.Files.Add($RootItem.Name, $sBytes, $true) 

    $AllFields = $RootItem.Item.Fields | ? {!($_.sealed)} 

    foreach($Field in $AllFields) 
    { 
        if($RootItem.Properties[$Field.Title]) 
        { 
            if(!($dFile.Properties[$Field.title])) 
            { 
                $dFile.AddProperty($Field.Title, $RootItem.Properties[$Field.Title]) 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                $dFile.Properties[$Field.Title] = $RootItem.Properties[$Field.Title] 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    $dFile.Update() 
} 

foreach($Folder in $AllFolders) 
{ 
    Remove-Variable ParentFolderURL 
    $i = 0 

    $FolderURL = $Folder.url.Split("/") 

    while($i -lt ($FolderURL.count-1)) 
    { 
    $ParentFolderURL = "$ParentFolderURL/" + $FolderURL[$i] 
    $i++ 
    } 

    $CurrentFolder = $dList.Folders | ? {$_.url -eq $ParentFolderURL.substring(1)} 
    if(!($CurrentFolder.Folders | ? {$_.name -eq $Folder.Name})) 
    { 
        $NewFolder = $dlist.Folders.Add(("$DestinationWebURL" + $ParentFolderURL), [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder, $Folder.name) 
        $NewFolder.update() 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $NewFolder = $dList.Folders | ? {$_.name -eq $Folder.Name} 
    } 
    $AllFiles = $sList.Items 
    $sItems = $Folder.folder.Files 

    if($Folder.Folder.Files.count -gt 0) 
    { 
        foreach($item in $sItems) 
        { 

            $Relative = ($Item.ServerRelativeUrl).substring(1) 
            $TargetItem = $AllFiles | ? {$_.URL -eq $Relative} 
            $sBytes = $TargetItem.File.OpenBinary() 
            $dFile = $Newfolder.Folder.Files.Add($TargetItem.Name, $sBytes, $true) 
            $AllFields = $TargetItem.Fields | ? {!($_.sealed)} 

            foreach($Field in $AllFields) 
            { 
                if($TargetItem.Properties[$Field.Title]) 
                { 
                    if(!($dFile.Properties[$Field.title])) 
                    { 
                        $dFile.AddProperty($Field.Title, $TargetItem.Properties[$Field.Title]) 
                    } 
                    else 
                    { 
                        $dFile.Properties[$Field.Title] = $TargetItem.Properties[$Field.Title] 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
            $dFile.Update() 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Reference: [Copy all SharePoint Files and Folders Using PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Copy-all-SharePoint-Files-0999c53f)